# Drupal View 3 / CiviCRM integration - block update depends on user authorization

Tags: views, caching, civicrm

All,

In my CiviCRM installation, I support both Individual Contacts and Organization Contacts. For the Drupal site, there is a block based on a view that exposes some information about Organization Contacts. This view is configured with a Global: Random sort criteria in order to expose three different Organization on each page visit.

When I am logged into the site (as an Authenticated User or Administrator), the block works properly. When I am not logged into the site, the block does not update. Just to be clear: When logged in, reloading the same page results in three different Organization Contacts being displayed. When not logged in, the same three Organization Contacts are displayed each time.

The issue seems to be tied to the cache. When I cleared the Drupal caches, the Organization Contacts for the non-logged in user changed (but then remained the same as described above).

Would you please suggest a fix for this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Obviously one could just "turn caching off", but that's not necessarily a good idea. How do you know that your servers can handle the increased load? How much extra loading time are you willing to accept, etc. There are a number of things that must be considered to "suggest a fix for this problem".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's a way around this. Drupal will cache the output of Views to anonymous users, as it does for most pages. Drupal rarely caches content for authenticated users. On top of that, your host may be using a reverse-cache such as Varnish, since it greatly improves performance of Drupal sites for anonymous users.

A workaround could be to reduce the cache time of content. First try by changing the cache settings on the specific View, and if not, try the global setting in /admin/config/development/performance.

However, assuming that the list of contacts you are displaying is a sort of "randomly featured members" type of block, if your cache expires every 15 or 30 minutes, it's still usually pretty sufficient for that type of requirement, unless you have a really high traffic site and you must rotate faster.

If you do have a *very* high traffic site, I would probably load the block dynamically with Ajax to avoid killing the cache (and cache that block in a more efficient cache such as memcached, which a short expiration time of perhaps 5 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

> The issue seems to be tied to the cache.

You are perfectly right, it is. It may be block cache, but more probably it is page cache or even Boost. Instead of various workarounds like short cache or DRUPAL_NO_CACHE that can be ignored by Boost, Varnish etc, I prefer different way:

- I create an empty place for data that is supposed to be random. This means that page may be cached, no problem.
- Using AJAX, I fill it with random data. Page is already rendered, user sees no delay. I use some nice effect for first portion of data to appear.
- Additional bonus: Using timer, I can shuffle data even if user is not reloading my page.

Answer (score 0):

In hook_block_info I would try using https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/constant/DRUPAL_NO_CACHE/7